# custom topbar with tabbar functionality and hidden

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to create a top bar with 5 labels. each label will show viewcontroller.

Can I create tabbar, add 5 viewcontroller, hide the tabbar, and each time press the top bar label, it will hide/show the correct viewcontroller through the tabbar functionality ?

if I'm wrong with this approach what do you recommend for this requierment ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you, you need to use tabBarController.selectedIndex = (int)index; to change the selected tab. Please correct me if i misunderstand you